# jni program,dependency about some .so,.a library.but loadlibrary func can only link dynamic library,what about static library

Tags: java, linux

jni need to load library,and the library is based on some static library.but when execute jni,i got und symbol which is defined in the static library.

i used the static library to build a dynamic library,and in the java program,load the dynamic library.

Makefile:

```
sudo cp /home/daniel/projects/leveldb/libleveldb.a libleveldb.a
g++ -shared -o libTest.so -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux/ -L. -L/usr/lib/vmware-ovftool/lib/ libleveldb.a -lpthread Test.cpp
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <leveldb/db.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_getStringFromC(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
 printf("world\n");
 cout<<"hahaha\n";
 leveldb::DB *db = nullptr;
 leveldb::Options options;

 options.create_if_missing = true;

 leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/tmp/testdb",&db);
...
```

cmd : java Test
result:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libTest.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
```

cmd:readelf -s libleveldb.a|grep leveldb7Options
result:

```
169: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
109: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
48: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
 8: 0000000000000000   108 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC2Ev
12: 0000000000000000   108 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _ZN7leveldb7OptionsC1Ev
```

so this means that,i can find the symbol in static library,but the dynamic library base on libleveldb.a,in which jni program can't find the same symbol.
and i want to know the reason and the right way to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

To use static library you need to statically link it with your executable file.

In case of Java it mean you need to link it with `java` executable.It means you need to reassembly it each time you run your Java application, but it will be very inconvenient.

Comment: what do you mean by "reassembly it each time you run"?would you mind describe the step more concretely?

Comment: I mean you need statically link your lib because different app will require different libs.

Comment: but how does java program link *.a library in linux?i thought java program can only link *.so and jar file.